# Spring data rest application not getting data from database after implementing redis caching

Tags: redis, spring-data, repository, hal

I am working on implementing Redis caching for my spring data rest (hal) api.
Requirement: cache all data to redis after first call to database and perform operations on redis.
like Add record should first happen in cache and then inserted in database in a transaction.

I implemented caching for one of the JpaRepository, but when I do implicit findAll by calling the /states endpoint, I get no records, even when I have 10k records in database.

Please help guys!!

Below is my config:

**MyServicesApplication.java**

```java
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableCaching
@EnableRedisRepositories
public class MyServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PartnerServicesApplication.class, args);

    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner init(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return args -> {

        };
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```java
springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /api-docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /swagger-ui-custom.html
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
      FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS: false
    date-format: MM/dd/yyyy
#    time-zone: EST
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    password: mysecretpassword
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres?currentSchema=public
    username: postgres
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
        max_size: 2
        min_size: 2
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    show-sql: true
  cache:
    redis:
      cache-null-values: false
      time-to-live: 600000
      use-key-prefix: true
    type: redis
  redis:
    host: localhost
    port: 6379
    password:
```

**Jpa Entity State.java**

```java
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisHash;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Optional;

@Entity
@Table(name = "my_state")
@RedisHash
public class State extends BaseAuditDetails {

    @Id
    @org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
    @Column(name = "cde_st", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private String cdeSt;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "nam_st", nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String namSt;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "dte_inact", table = "state")

    private LocalDate dteInact;


    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ind_dst_obsv", nullable = false)
    private Character indDstObsv;

    public String getCdeSt() {
        return cdeSt;
    }

    public void setCdeSt(String cdeSt) {
        this.cdeSt = cdeSt;
    }

    public Optional<String> getNamSt() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(namSt);
    }

    public void setNamSt(String namSt) {
        this.namSt = namSt;
    }

    public Optional<LocalDate> getDteInact() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(dteInact);
    }

    public void setDteInact(LocalDate dteInact) {
        this.dteInact = dteInact;
    }


    public Optional<Character> getIndDstObsv() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(indDstObsv);
    }

    public void setIndDstObsv(Character indDstObsv) {
        this.indDstObsv = indDstObsv;
    }

}
```

**MyStateRepository.java**

```java
import com.devstartshop.myapp.entities.State;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Generated by Spring Data Generator on 16/03/2020
 */
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MyStateRepository extends JpaRepository<State, String> {
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "state")
    List<State> findAll();

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "state")
    List<State> findAll(Sort sort);

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "state")
    State getOne(String s);

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "state")
    Page<State> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "state")
    Optional<State> findById(String s);
}
```

**Dependencies in build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-core:1.1.49'
    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.1.49'
    implementation 'io.github.classgraph:classgraph:4.8.44'
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.2.2'
//    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.30'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-pool2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-explorer'
    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.10.Final'
    implementation 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.2.Final'
    implementation 'com.github.kuros:random-jpa:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.10.0'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.9'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compileOnly 'com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.2.2'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out that using @RedisHash annotation will only make transactions to the Redis database.
So I took a different approach to use @Cacheable on all GET calls and @CacheEvict on all other calls responsible to make changes to database.

Probably @RedisHash is meant for using Redis as a transaction database which can be persisted to a persistent database like postgres using some other process.