# Using spring data rest with postgresql and cache as redis

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-redis

I have a simple model with repository configured persisting to postgresql. Using `spring-data-rest`, the api's are available out of the box for all the crud operations.
Now I want to introduce the caching with redis-6.0. So that any write(rest api's for POST or PUT, DELETE) operation, the model is persisted to db first and updated to the cache.

For the read operation(rest api GET), the item is looked into cache first, if available, then use that or else use spring-data-rest default behavior in this case i.e. find it in postgresql.

## Write Operations (POST, PUT, DELETE):

Using the `RepositoryEventHandler`, `HandleAfterCreate`, `HandleAfterDelete`, `HandleAfterSave` events are subscribed and used to sync up the cache. This reasonably keep the cache to latest.

## Read Operations(GET):

I do not see any event listener for read operation. Read is the only operation, that I want to bypass hitting the db as much as possible. But currently do not find a way to do this.

Please let me know, if there is a way to listen for the read operation and do cache lookup first.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to avoid writing the custom controller for GET as it overrides the default implementation. The default implementations provide usefule links of that entity like
`
"_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/person/1"
    },
    "person": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/person/1{?projection}",
      "templated": true
    },
    "categories": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8082/person/1/categories{?projection}",
      "templated": true
    }
`

Comment: I did not see it before but there is a similar question asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750063/spring-data-rest-application-not-getting-data-from-database-after-implementing-r
I am trying that to suit my need.

Comment: Now I decided to use redis for storing the entities. I currently do not have complex query needed to fetch data and redis is good to serve my need. I am using redis cluster inside kubernetes with spring-data-rest. I don't have any proper benchmark testing but the response is quite fast with redis. With redis-cli, I could now checkpoint the data and so far it redis holds really good.

Comment: I am not exactly sure why you are managing the cache yourself. Configure the cache for you JPA provider and be done with it.

Comment: @AlanHay I was thinking about having only redis as persistent layer and foregot the postgresql. I need to some more test to go to decide on that. Now, I did exactly as you mentioned. The cache is now managed through spring with redis and persisted to postgresql.

Comment: At the time, I asked this question, I was not sure about where/what to configure for caching. With going through examples, it is now working.